# Google play games login flow

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am working on an app that's using Google Play Games Services. I'm currently working on the homescreen activity and I want the log in flow to work the same as flappy bird does.

In flappy bird (this is just an example, I'm sure a lot of other apps work like this too)...

1. There is no sign in button
2. If the user clicks on the Leaderboard or Rate button, it asks you to sign in.
3. If you are not signed in, you can still play offline

I want my code to implement this but I'm having some difficulty. Firstly, my app KEEPS on asking me to sign in every time I start the activity, it's not remembering that I've previously signed in. I would appreciate some help with my following code.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class HomeScreenActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Button playButton, leaderboardButton;
    private Context appContext;
    private static final int GAME_INTENT = 1000;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    // Request code to use when launching the resolution activity
    private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 1001;
    private static final int REQUEST_LEADERBOARD = 1002;
    // Unique tag for the error dialog fragment
    private static final String DIALOG_ERROR = "dialog_error";
    // Bool to track whether the app is already resolving an error
    private boolean mResolvingError = false;
    private static final String STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR = "resolving_error";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen_layout);

        mResolvingError = savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, false);

        appContext = getApplicationContext();

        findViews();
        attachListeners();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Games.API)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mResolvingError) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, mResolvingError);
    }

    private void findViews() {
        playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        leaderboardButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.leaderboard_button);
    }

    private void attachListeners() {
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(appContext, InGameActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, GAME_INTENT);
            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case GAME_INTENT:
            // upload data to leaderboards
            break;
        case REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR:
            mResolvingError = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to
                // connect
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()
                        && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (mResolvingError) {
            // Already attempting to resolve an error.
            return;
        } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mResolvingError = true;
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Show dialog using GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()
            showErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode());
            mResolvingError = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.d("LOG", "+++++ onConnected +++++");
        leaderboardButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(
                        mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_highest_score)), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        Log.d("LOG", "+++++ onConnectionSuspended +++++");
        leaderboardButton.setOnClickListener(null);
    }

     /* Creates a dialog for an error message */
    private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
        // Create a fragment for the error dialog
        ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
        // Pass the error that should be displayed
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DIALOG_ERROR, errorCode);
        dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
        dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "errordialog");
    }

    /* Called from ErrorDialogFragment when the dialog is dismissed. */
    public void onDialogDismissed() {
        mResolvingError = false;
    }

    /* A fragment to display an error dialog */
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public ErrorDialogFragment() { }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Get the error code and retrieve the appropriate dialog
            int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ERROR);
            return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode,
                    this.getActivity(), REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            ((HomeScreenActivity)getActivity()).onDialogDismissed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to maintain and check for the state yourself if you are not using [BaseGameUtils](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples) to perform the sign-in and other Play Games related tasks. This is quite messy, but you can have a look at the `GameHelper` class in this package to see how Google does it.

I would advise you to use the `BaseGameUtils` package, and instead of extending `BaseGameActivity` just use the [GameHelper directly](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#using_gamehelper_without_basegameactivity). This takes a lot of the pain out of working with the Play Games serivice.

Comment: Nevermind that, what I really wanted to ask was this: When I go to the BaseGameActivity class, it says that I need to get the user to press a button to sign in to the game via `beginUserInitiatedSignIn` but how does flappybird sign you in automatically? I have the flappy bird app and there is no sign in button at all. How have they done this?>

Comment: Simple, you can call the `beginUserInitiatedSignIn()` in response to **any** event, such as when the game ends (before posting scores to the leaderboard). However, Google's guidelines suggest that you keep the user signed-in for the duration of the app. So you sign-in on launch (this will only prompt the user on the first launch, to choose an account) and that connection remains alive until your app leaves the foreground, and is re-established when it regains focus.

Comment: Additionally, your app is NOT in constant contact with Google's servers, but rather it communicates with the Play Games app. This app then periodically syncs with the servers (through the Play Services app). Only some features, such as cloud save, communicates immediately with the cloud, and requires an active connection. Achievements and leaderboards are cached in the Play Games app if no connection is available, as long as your player is signed-in.

Comment: I see, okay. I'm going to change my entire code to use BaseGameUtils. Thanks for the advice.